# JMenuBar makes JFrame "jump"

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a Java application of a sea map, where I use a JFrame as Canvas to draw the sea itself. I have a GUI on top of this as a JPanel. I recently added a JMenuBar to the JPanel with different functions. However, I noticed now that the the newly added MenuBar 'pushes the application' downwards ~10-15 pixels — and when I zoom/pan the map, the map makes some weird 'jumps' – likely trying to readjust.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Could be a lot of things. For more specific help, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Nine out of ten, you need to be looking at insets.

It's been a while since I used Swing directly, but all containers have a method called getInsets(). This returns an Insets object, describing the size of the border of the container--including your JFrame. JMenuBars tend to nudge those insets a bit, leaving you two two main options.

What I recommend is doing your drawing to a JPanel, placed in the JFrame; so that you don't have to worry about the JMenuBar. Use the panel as a canvas instead.

The other option is to poll for the insets at the time of drawing, and alter your coordinates accordingly; but I have to recommend against this if you can still avoid it, as it runs against just about all of my modular programming instincts.